# Setup integrated terminal of vs-code with anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have installed the latest anaconda python distribution and as well vs-code editor. When vs-code is used and its terminal prompt invoked I have no Anaconda Prompt available at start respectively integrated terminal has no Anaconda prompt with vs-code environment.

How and where the vs-code editor should be set up with enabled Anaconda prompt terminal?

Moreover, I would like to create a separate python/conda environment within Anaconda and redirect execution there whilst staying with vs-code and its terminal.

I expect the indication for this Anaconda terminal within prompt e.g.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\
```

In the vs-code command prompt, I have

```
PS C:\Users\
```

Comment: Add your Anaconda folder to system `path` so that PowerShell and cmd have access to conda.exe and then you can just use conda from terminal in VSCode.

Comment: See the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Please follow the tutorial @AMC post and have a try. If there's any question, please let us know.

Comment: the recommended solution does not work, no available virtual environment, it can't be switched, just base is available

Comment: @Jack Did you specify a Python version when creating the env? Also, did you see the "Additional notes" on that section of the page?

Comment: `File C:\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at       
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess` virtual environment can't be switched

Answer (score 0):

In Settings.json, add `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true` to make sure when opening a new integrated Terminal, the virtual environment can be activated automatically.

1.Press **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open an integrated Terminal, run

```
    conda create -n .venv python=3.8
```

Then you should get the .venv created successfully:

[image]

2.You may see the tips, then activate the .venv:

[image]

3.Open **Command Palette**, select the interpreter by manually entering the path to `python.exe`, the environment location you can get from the information shown under the create command. Now the python interpreter shown in the left bottom corner should be: [image]

4.Click the green button in the top right corner to **Run Python File in Terminal**, which will open a new integrated Terminal and environment is activated automatically:

[image]

Please follow my steps and have a try. If there's any questions, don't hesitate to let me know.